# Content extends beyond 100% of screen div

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage thats supposed to look like this:

[image]

But unfortunately, the content div (the purple div in the image) is 100% of the original height of the screen, but doesn't expand when the content inside is larger. I tried adding a `.clearfix{clear:both;}` in between the end of the content and the end of the content div, but it didn't work.

Thanks for all help!

Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xCcdB/

---

Edit: When I say "end of screen", I really just mean goes all the way to the bottom of the screen, even if you have to scroll down a ways.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. Please rephrase / clean up the question so that your actual request is clear.

Comment: Add a padding:5px; to make it look better.

Comment: @ChrisMukherjee, Sorry I was unclear. Basically, without any content in the white content div, the div extends all the way to the bottom: see http://jsfiddle.net/xCcdB/1/. But with some text in the content div that are larger than the content div, it looks like: http://jsfiddle.net/xCcdB. I want the content div to always extend to the bottom

Comment: It would have been much clearer if you didn't have the blue (#158) of the `tags` covering the bottom. I removed the blue background and can see the problem now.

Comment: @ChrisMukherjee, sorry I put that in on my computer to test and forgot to remove it when I did the JSFiddle, heres removed: http://jsfiddle.net/xCcdB/2/

Comment: Not a problem. Is my solution below satisfactory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the position of the `.content` to `position:absolute`.

See it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/xCcdB/3/

Comment: Mukhrejee, thanks for the answer, but this un-centers the content div. Is there a way to get an absolute-positioned div to center?

Comment: Before the relatively positioned content div was just floating above the text covering some of it. Now the content div is absolutely positioned around all the text. This means that it will extend from the top of the text all the way to the bottom, and from the left of the text all the way to the right. Do you not want it to cover the right part of the text?

Comment: Sorry I wanted it to cover all of the text, I just was saying that adding `position:absolute` makes the content div no longer centered on the screen. I just added `padding-bottom:2em;` to the content div and it worked, see: http://jsfiddle.net/xCcdB/4/ . Thanks for the help though, I accepted your answer.